Questions on Box and whiskers diagram
I am trying to find the best method to determine which direction the distribution is skewed by looking at the box and whisker plot(not using mean).
I understand the "obvious" problems like: link where both the wisker and box is very compressed on one side, making an obvious skewness to the other side.
After googling I am getting mixed instructions:
Method1, source link, suggests that we only compare the whiskers.
Method2, source link, suggests we need to have the right whisker longer and the left box smaller for positively skewed(not sure if they mean we must have both true or we can have either one true to determine skewness).
Both below are positively skewed:

I feel like the first method is not really useful as in example b) the wiskers are the same length which according to method 1, will suggest no skewness but we know its skewed as the median is to the left.
For the second method (assuming they mean right whisker longer OR the left box smaller to prove positive skewness) works better as we are able to answer both examples.
$\textbf{Question 1}$
Does this mean that method1 is bad(why do they tell us to do it like this)? Due to different sites suggesting different methods\approaches I am not 100% sure and would like advice on the correct method(and possibly a different\better method) to use.
$\textbf{Question 2}$
Suppose we have the case where the whisker is longer on the right but the box is longer on the left:
How do we tell which way is skewed?

Skewness is difficult to discern from a box-and-whisker plot, so I would not assume that in general one can assert extent of skew from such diagrams.
In cases where we can make assumptions about the underlying distribution from which observations are realized, then yes, we may be able to infer skewness from the box plots.  But there is no universal rule:  one should instead look at a histogram.
To understand why, think of the box plot as representing equal quarters of data:  $1/4^{\rm th}$ of the data occur in each whisker and on each side of the box, assuming no outliers.  If you know the sample size, you could distribute data points inside each segment of the box plot, like this:

Or this:

Or this:

Or this:

The point is that within each segment of the plot, you don't know how the data are distributed.

Heropup wrote a pretty good answer, but I wanted to add an answer under the assumption that all the data points would be evenly distributed within their respective quartiles. Since each box and each whisker represents $25$% of the data points, it makes sense that the data points should get more concentrated as the box/whisker gets shorter. Then we have to determine which side of the box-whisker plot is more scrunched together on average (which half is shorter). The shorter side of the plot is where the data points are more concentrated on average, and you can use that to infer general skewness.
